# How to mouseenter with live elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with mouseenter with live element. The functions is not triggered when I hover over a selected element added with javacript.

I add the elements with this:

```
this.fixElements = function () {
    $('.iconstarsdynamic.isgradeable:not(.touched)').each(function(){
        var $self = $(this),
                $gradeLength = Math.round(parseInt($self.width())/$maxGrade*100)/100;

        $self.addClass('touched');

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxGrade; ++$i) {
            $('<span />', {
                "class" : "grader",
                "z-index" : $i,
                "width" : ($gradeLength*$i)+'px'
            }).attr('grade', $i).appendTo($self);
        }
    });
}
```

And i try to `mouseenter` with this:

```
this.hover = function() {
    $('.iconstarsdynamic.isgradeable')
        .on('mouseenter', '.grader', function(){
            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
            console.log('over');
        })
        .on('mouseleave', '.grader', function(){
            $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
<span class="iconstarsdynamic isgradeable touched" title="Rated 0 out of 4">
    <span class="stars" style="width:0%;"></span>
    <span class="grader" z-index="1" style="width: 9.25px; " grade="1"></span>
    <span class="grader" z-index="2" style="width: 18.5px; " grade="2"></span>
    <span class="grader" z-index="3" style="width: 27.75px; " grade="3"></span>
    <span class="grader" z-index="4" style="width: 37px; " grade="4"></span>
</span>
```

Problem is that the `mouseenter` never runs. Why is this? It works if I attach `mouseenter` to `.iconstarsdynamic.isgradeable`, but that's not what I want. I want it attached to `.iconstarsdynamic.isgradeable .grader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) events do not bubble up and therefore won't work with event delegation methods like you use. You should use `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead (you may have to take care of descendants' events, if any).

Comment: I've tried with `mouseover` and `mouseout`, same problem, nothing happends.

Comment: Yes, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/x57Ec/. But are you trying to make the hovered element visible on hovering? The `mouseover` event will only fire on visible elements, otherwise you should use `opacity: 0` to hide the elements.

Comment: The elements was hidden with `visibility:hidden`, didn't know that it couldn't have that. Thanks.